# What does $\mathbb{Z}_{7429}$ mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

What exactly does $\mathbb{Z}_{7429}$ mean?
 Is it the set of all integers up to and including 7429?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I choose to answer with a more complete explanation because I once also thought that $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{ -(n-1), ..., 0, ..., n-1\}$

To fully understand this [**group**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29), you must understand the equivalence relation congruence modulo $n$. We say that $(a,b) \in R$ or using an equivalent notation $aRb$ iff $a = b+nk$ $,k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

As an example: congruence modulo $2$.

$(2,4)$ is an element of this relation because $2 = 4 + 2k$, namely $k=-1$.

Now we define the equivalence class of the relation congruence modulo $n$ as following:
$$\bar{a} = \{b \mid aRb \}$$
going back to our example of congruence modulo $2$, this would mean that, for example:
$$\bar{2}= \{b\mid2Rb\} = \{b\mid2=b+2k \} = \{0,2,-2,...\} = \bar{4} = ...$$

Now we can finally define $\mathbb{Z}_n$:
$$\mathbb{Z}_n = \{\bar{0},...,\overline{n-1}\}$$

Hopefully this makes things a bit clearer for you.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, that makes a bit more sense!

Comment: To be more complete, we should consider the ring $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +, \cdot)$, as the existence of the additive group is therein implied.

Answer (score 7):

For the Additive Group of Integers Modulo $m$. which is a cyclic group, the notation $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is often used.

This is the group where $7429\equiv0$ with the usual addition.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_p$ is also used for the ring of $p$-adic integers but this does not apply to 7429 because it is not prime.

Answer (score 6):

Another notation for $\mathbb{Z}/7429\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: I find this notation better than $\mathbb Z_{7429}$ because of the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: @QiL: Using $\mathbb{Z_{7429}}$ makes me confused as well.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}_{7429}$ is the set of all integers modulo $7429$.